# Billboard.js: Let x-ticks overflow svg when padding is 0

Tags: billboard.js

I am creating a some charts with billboard.js and stumbled upon some overflow logic i can't sort out.

Case: A simple linechart w/o labels on y-axis (these will be solved on a container level and not in the chart). I want the chart to have zero padding on x, to make it take upp the full width.

Issue: If the y-ticks are all 0, or something below 10 the x-ticks text will be cropped, thus not displaying it's full text on the first or last tick.

```
bb.generate({
    bindto: "#chart",
    grid: {
        y: {
            show: true
        },
        x: {
            show: false
        }
    },
    area: {
        linearGradient: true
    },
    data: {
        x: "x",
        columns: [
            [
                "x",
                "2022-10-23T07:31:00Z",
                "2022-10-23T07:32:00Z",
                "2022-10-23T07:33:00Z",
                "2022-10-23T07:34:00Z",
                "2022-10-23T07:35:00Z",
                "2022-10-23T07:36:00Z",
                "2022-10-23T07:37:00Z",
                "2022-10-23T07:38:00Z",
                "2022-10-23T07:39:00Z",
                "2022-10-23T07:40:00Z",
                "2022-10-23T07:41:00Z",
                "2022-10-23T07:42:00Z",
                "2022-10-23T07:43:00Z"
            ],
            [
                "yTicks",
                0,
                0,
                0,
                0,
                0,
                0,
                0,
                0,
                0,
                0,
                0,
                0,
                0,
                0
            ]
        ],
        types: {
            yTicks: "area"
        }
    },
    axis: {
        x: {
            tick: {
                format: "%H:%M:%S",
                fit: false
            },
            type: "timeseries",
            padding: {
                left: 0,
                right: 0
            }
        },
        y: {
            
            padding: {
                bottom: 0
            },
            tick: {
                show: false,
            }
            
        },
        line: {
            zerobased: true
          },
    },
    legend: {
        show: false
    },
});
```

[Link to codepen](https://codepen.io/adam-fagerstr-m/pen/zYaOvgM?editors=1010)

So is there a way to let the chart use all available width (padding 0 on x-tick) and display the full tick-text without setting y-label? Something like an overflow setting in plain css, but can't figure out a correct solution for svgs.

Answer (score 0):

The first & last tick text can be hidden when the tick's position are set close to the edge. In this case, tick text can't be fully visible.

The easiest way to solve this, is giving some left/right padding.
Checkout the example.

```js
bb.generate({
    size: {
      width:500
    },
    padding: {
          left: 20,
          right: 20
    },
    grid: {
        y: {
            show: true
        },
        x: {
            show: false
        }
    },
    area: {
        linearGradient: true
    },
    data: {
        x: "x",
        columns: [
            [
                "x",
                "2022-10-23T07:31:00Z",
                "2022-10-23T07:32:00Z",
                "2022-10-23T07:33:00Z",
                "2022-10-23T07:34:00Z",
                "2022-10-23T07:35:00Z",
                "2022-10-23T07:36:00Z",
                "2022-10-23T07:37:00Z",
                "2022-10-23T07:38:00Z",
                "2022-10-23T07:39:00Z",
                "2022-10-23T07:40:00Z",
                "2022-10-23T07:41:00Z",
                "2022-10-23T07:42:00Z",
                "2022-10-23T07:43:00Z"
            ],
            [
                "yTicks",
                0,
                0,
                0,
                0,
                0,
                0,
                0,
                0,
                0,
                0,
                0,
                0,
                0,
                0
            ]
        ],
        types: {
            'yTicks': "area"
        }
    },
    clipPath: false,
    axis: {
        x: {
            clipPath: false,
            tick: {
                format: "%H:%M:%S",
                fit: true,
                //count:2,
                values: [
                // "2022-10-23T07:31:00Z",
                "2022-10-23T07:32:00Z",
                //"2022-10-23T07:33:00Z",
                //"2022-10-23T07:34:00Z",
                //"2022-10-23T07:35:00Z",
                "2022-10-23T07:36:00Z",
                //"2022-10-23T07:37:00Z",
                //"2022-10-23T07:38:00Z",
                //"2022-10-23T07:39:00Z",
                "2022-10-23T07:40:00Z",
                //"2022-10-23T07:41:00Z",
                //"2022-10-23T07:42:00Z",
                "2022-10-23T07:43:00Z"
                ],
            },
            type: "timeseries",
            padding: {
                left: 0,
                right: 0
            }
        },
        y: {
            show: false
            
        },
        line: {
            zerobased: true
          },
    },
    legend: {
        show: false
    },
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/billboard.js/dist/theme/datalab.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/billboard.js/dist/billboard.pkgd.js"></script>
  </head>
<body>
  <div id="chart"></div>
</body>
</html>
```